# How do you find the length of an array in V+

Tags: arrays, v+

If i have an array, like the following:

```
my.arr[0] = 0;
my.arr[5] = 5;
```

How do i find the length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the last index by using [`LAST`](http://www1.adept.com/main/KE/data/V%20Plus/V%20Language%20Reference/last_r.html), ie:

```
LAST(my.arr[])
```

would give you:

```
5
```

so the length could be found like this:

```
length = LAST(my.arr[]) + 1
```

but you would use it in a `for` loop like this:

```
FOR i = 0 to LAST(my.arr[])
   IF DEFINED(my.arr[i]) THEN
      TYPE my.arr[i]
   END
END
```